# What is the event fired when the user press tab on the keyboard?

Tags: javascript

I'm assuming the user doesn't have a mouse (or any pointer device). Only a keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Use `keydown`

So for example:

```
if(event.keyCode === 9) { //tab
   //do something
}
```